# How to get string value from object datatype column in python dataframe which have combination of datatype values in column

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I want to get row from this dataframe which have string value in column "city".

```
  | city  | region
0 | 5     | 19
1 | Pakri | 37
2 | 9     | 26
3 | 452   | 59
4 | 66    | 2
5 | 226   | 19
```

Answer should like the below snippet which contain row that have string value in its first column

```
  | city  | region
0 | Pakri | 37
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a boolean filter using apply to the pandas DataFrame o Series.

consider:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#create a series
s=  pd.Series([5,100,'string'], dtype=object)

#set type to string 
s =  s.astype(str)

# apply
temp = s.apply(lambda x: x.isdigit())


#return
#(0, True) (1, True) (2, False)

#index of the string
index = np.where(temp == False)
    
#select by index 
s.loc[index]

#return
# (2, 'string')
```

Comment: No, I want to select by datatype of column value

Comment: @anmolreview the answer was edited according to your request, greetings, Chelo.

Comment: @anmolreview Don't mention it, if this answer was helpful please mark it as correct with the check symbol. Greetings, Marcelo.